# How to run a .net core web api locally on Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created a web api that I can run locally in Visual Studio on localhost and I can access Swagger via. http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html.

I've created a Dockerfile and executed `docker build -t test .` and I can see the image created in Docker Desktop. When running it, I don't get any error and I get these logs:

```
=info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]

      Now listening on: http://[::]:80

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Hosting environment: Production

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Content root path: /app
```

What do I need to do to make the web api accessible via. a browser?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to map the port of the container to some port on the host. Can you add the command you use to run the container?

Comment: @Salketer I used Docker Desktop and its UI to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS to `http://+:80` in their base images, so your app is listening on port 80 when it runs in a container.

You should also be aware that Swagger normally isn't available in a container, because Swagger by default only is available when running in development environments. A container is not considered development by default.

So to run your container and have access to Swagger, you should run your container using a command that looks something like

```
docker run --rm -d -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -p 5000:80 test
```

You should then be able to access your webapi on http://localhost:5000/ and have Swagger available.

Comment: "docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use."

Comment: You need to stop and remove any containers first that use port 5000. Or use another port.

Answer (score 0):

For me ASPNETCORE_URLS was not working and the reason was that it was overriden by UseUrls that was getting the url from my appsettings:
"Urls": "http://localhost:5000"

Even when i commented out the UseUrls() in the Program.cs it was still picking up the url from the appsettings.json automatically!

I changed the value in my appsettings.json from:
"Urls": "http://localhost:5000"
to
"Urls": "http://+:5000"
and now my app is accessible to any port i forward it to,

Assuming we run a new container publishing the port:
-p 5001:5000
then the api will be accessible at localhost:5001 from my browser